# SVN : Get target branch where the commit is happening in python pre-commit hook

Tags: python, svn, version-control, hook, pre-commit

I am writing my pre-commit hook file in python for SVN repository.

I have more than one branches.

I want to know from which branch the commit has come from, for example, trunk, or branch1.1 or etc.

Is there any way I can find from which branch the commit is coming from in pythonic way in pre-commit script?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you try *anything* ?

Comment: Yes @LazyBadger, I tried `svnlook dirs-changed /var/svn/repos -t <transaction>`

it worked! :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- PySVN: [pysvn.Transaction.changed](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_transaction): "Return a dict of all changes in the transaction"
- Call process `svnlook dirs-changed <OPTIONS>` from Python